# Exclude few dates in a month in mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

Below is my query. My requirement here is I want to exclude a few dates sales in a particular month while I am looking for month wise data.

For example: I don't want to include Aug 15, 2008 date sales for the month of August, 2008 when I am looking 2008 year for the month of August, 2008 data for accessories product.

```
select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,([Product].[Category].&[4], 
[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
)on 1
from [Adventure Works]
where [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008].
```

I would appropriate, if you could help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the member within the Where clause:

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
([Product].[Category].&[4],[Date].[Calendar].[Month]) on 1
from [Adventure Works] 
where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008],{[Date].[Day].[Day].Members - [Date].[Day].&[20080815]})
```

Comment: it shows same result when execute both the query which were below. I mean day members excluded from the month                                                           select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
([Product].[Category].&[4],[Date].[Calendar].[Month]) on 1
from [Adventure Works] 
where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008],{[Date].[Date].[Date].Members - [Date].[Date].&[20080131]})


select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
([Product].[Category].&[4],[Date].[Calendar].[Month]) on 1
from [Adventure Works] 
where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008])

Comment: Do you mean [Date].[Date].&[20080131] member value isn't excluded?? Could you please provide result screenshots? Plus day members values.

Comment: Yes the day sales of 20080131 is not excluded from the month of January,2008. Sure i do upload screen shots

Comment: I am not sure how to upload the images but following results are getting "Accessories January 2008 $56,456.93"     for before and after exclude

Comment: Okay, are you sure that [Date].[Date].&[20080131] is a real member? Will it work with the following code: where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008],[Date].[Date].&[20080815])

Comment: Yes, its a real member 20080131 which has data in the cube. we did not chose 20080815 as a member in our example as it dosnot have data either both olap & oltp systems. Can you please let me know if any alternatives to exclude members.

Comment: Okay, where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008],[Date].[Date].&[20080131]) will return a value?  where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008],{[Date].[Date].[Date].Members - [Date].[Date].&[20080131]}) won't exclude the member? Are you sure?